# Disabled EditText element display keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, scrollview

I need to figure out why I keep getting the android keyboard displayed, since I have my **EditText** with the enabled attribute set to false. The root element of my layout file is a **ScrollView**. When I take out the ScrollView element, it works perfectly with a root element like LinearLayout.

Is this the expected behavior for a ScrollView, or it's just a buggy thing? (I do not get the point to have a ScrollView with a text editable element behavior, if that is the case).

Just as an extra, some of my layout code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/input_name_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_idcard_icon"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/personal_setting_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input_name_icon"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="First Name" />
```

Don't stress out, I'll change my string and dimensions properly... ;D

Comment: Looks like buggy behavior (however, there's always possibility that it's broken in other part of your code). Have you tried to workaround with android:focusable="false"?

Comment: No, but, do I need to set focusable back to true when I make it enabled?

Comment: Sure, you do need to set it to true then needed. Same as enabled.

Comment: Ok, that worked, and I found another solution adding this attribute to my Activity definition at manifest (android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden") solved it too.

Comment: Great, looks like ScrollView handles focus some specific way and makes edit focused before it disabled. BTW, you can add your answer to the question and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the android keyboard from showing up every time you open your activity with ScrollView you have to place `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` but not in the EditText. You have to put it in the ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="copsonic.com.SoundExchange.demoApp.FragmentTransmitter">


    <!-- Common template for all fragments -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextmessage2Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_send_msg"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" >

        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>
```